# EXT:tt_news <link> in RSS feed

Tags: rss, typo3, tt-news

I'm trying to set up an RSS Feed through tt_news in TYPO3:  http://www.familieistzukunft.ch/home/?type=100

The links in the RSS feed are not proper HTML. They turn up like this:

```
<link http://www.familieistzukunft.ch/details/...80780691f/ - external-link-new-window "Opens external link in new window">Kommentar</link>
```

I did the template like this:

```
<content:encoded> <![CDATA[###NEWS_CONTENT###]]> </content:encoded>
```

So why does the CDATA tag not help? How do I fix this?

This is my TypoScript:

```
# RSS2
rss2 = PAGE
rss2 {
    typeNum = 100
    10 >
    10 < plugin.tt_news
    10.pid_list >
    10.pid_list = {$plugin.tt_news.pid_list}
    10.singlePid = {$plugin.tt_news.singlePid}
    10.defaultCode = XML
    10.displayXML.xmlFormat = rss2
    #wenn man archivierte News nicht mehr RSSen will
    10.archive = -1
    config {
        disableAllHeaderCode = 1
        additionalHeaders = Content-type:text/xml
        no_cache = 1
        xhtml_cleaning = 0
    }
}
#RSS 0.91
rss091 = PAGE
rss091 < rss2
rss091 {
    typeNum = 101
    10.displayXML.xmlFormat = rss091
}
#RDF
rdffeed = PAGE
rdffeed < rss2
rdffeed {
    typeNum = 102
    10.displayXML.xmlFormat = rdf
    #RDF kennt auch Feed-Images
    10.displayXML.xmlIcon = fileadmin/images/rdf.gif
}
#Atom
atom1 = PAGE
atom1 < rss2
atom1 {
    typeNum = 103
    10.displayXML.xmlFormat = atom1
}

page.headerData.110 = HTML
page.headerData.110.value = <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="News" href="http://www.familieistzukunft.ch/index.php?id=32&type=100">
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and solved it with the following code:

```
rss.10.displayXML {
xmlFormat = rss2
content_stdWrap {
  stripHtml = 0
  htmlSpecialChars = 0
  parseFunc < lib.parseFunc_RTE
  parseFunc.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines.nonWrappedTag >
}
```

}

The idea is the same but use `content_stdWrap` instead of `bodytext_stdWrap`. In my case I got problem using `htmlSpecialChars.preserveEntities = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks, like you are just putting raw content from DB to ###NEWS_CONTENT### marker.

You should use `pi_RTEcssText($rawContent);` from `tslib_pibase` class to convert all the raw content to proper HTML.

Comment: I don't understand?pi_RTEcssText($rawContent); from tslib_pibase How do I do this?

Comment: @eundd how do you output content of news to this feed?

Comment: I'm using tt_news I added my typoscript above. I don't know how to develop extensions...

Comment: Maybe there is a problem, because somewhere you unset **parseFunc**. I don't remember exact location of it in tt_news, but take a look at following [link](http://www.training-typo3.com/2011/06/16/tt_news-rss-feed-valid-and-with-images/), where comment says _# parse news subheader into <description> as (escaped) HTML_. There is **lib.parseFunc_RTE** used for subheader stdWrap. Same must be used for bodytext.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far! It's still not working added: xmlnews.10.displayXML {
bodytext_stdWrap {

# parse news subheader into <description> as (escaped) HTML
stripHtml = 0
htmlSpecialChars = 0
htmlSpecialChars.preserveEntities = 1
parseFunc < lib.parseFunc_RTE
parseFunc.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines.nonWrappedTag >
}
}

Comment: @eundd did you try something of this: `plugin.tt_news.general_stdWrap.parseFunc < lib.parseFunc_RTE` or `plugin.tt_news.displayList.content_stdWrap.parseFunc < lib.parseFunc_RTE`. Can you see, that parseFunc is assigned correctly in **TypoScript Object Browser**?

Comment: @eundd it looks correct. Seems like this configuration isn't applied at all... You need to look into source code of tt_news and see, what is wrong there.